# JFrog artifactory gives 403 Forbidden when started on localhost

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

Recently I installed jfrog artifactory on my machine as per installation instructions on the official website and couple of youTube videos.
When tried to start artifactory in local browser with http://localhost:8081 (as per artifactory website) I am getting 403 Forbidden

I tried couple of browsers and disabling the proxies in browser but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I tried using different post and scanning the artifactory start log and tried port 8040 (http://http://localhost:8040) instead of 8081 and it worked. Probably official document is mentioning incorrect port

Comment: which version of artifactory were you trying?